# Memory size exhausted

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

trying to install FOSUserBundle in Symfony 2.7 on XAMPP 5.6. When I'm typing in the project directory:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

So I set `memory_limit = -1` in php.ini in XAMPP but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you tried to increase your maximum memory limit to 64MB in your php.ini

Comment: Are you sure using last composer version? try executing `composer self-update`

Comment: try Refresh xamp?

Answer (score 0):

If you change something in the php.ini or appache.conf it will always require a **restart or reload**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

or

```
 php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors